# How to take data from current page and display in new page

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have created a wordpress theme using tutorials online so I am by no means an expert at this. My issue is I use a meta box to allow for custom fields in my theme, and I am having issues with the image portion of it. I can get the images to display how I want in thumbnails but I dont know how to take the same image order and open the images in full size on a new page. I want it to be very simple, just a pages that shows images one after another.

Here is an example of how the page looks http://gwenty.com/example/listings/10001-youbou-road-youbou/

Example code for the displaying of those thumbs

```
<?php
$images = rwmb_meta( 'YOUR_PREFIX_plupload', 'type=image' );
foreach ( $images as $image )
{
echo "<a href='{$image['full_url']}' title='{$image['title']}' rel='thickbox'><img  src='{$image['url']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' ></a>";
}
; ?>
```

Again what I want is the images to display in the same order but on a new page with just those same images. It seems simple, but not for me.... I dont need help with the css/html part of it just the code needed to use that data on a new page.

Comment: Have a look at sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php there are also some Wordpress plugins for better session management if you prefer, just google it

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with sessions.

Comment: I think this is a question specific to the plugin Meta Box. [what is rwmb_meta?] You should probably change the title, so that people familiar with the plugin can answer your question.